# Leiningen, :warn-on-reflection. Wanted for current project only

Tags: clojure, leiningen

If I switch :warn-on-reflection on in Leiningen (Ver. 2), I get warnings not only for the current project, but for dependencies too. (And, e.g. even if I call "lein help", it will e.g. warn about reflections in clucy - a dependency of leiningen itself.)

As these projects are out of my current scope, I want a possibility to restrict the warnings to the current project only. Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clojure namespace compilation is transitive. See: [Transitive AOT Compilation](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Transitive+AOT+Compilation)

Workaround, checkout clucy and:

```
→ lein compile :all
→ lein install
```

so the Clojure compiler will skip the compilation of clucy, because the classfiles already exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
```

at the top of your "main" .clj file. Right after `use` and `require` statements for external code, but before `require` and/or `load` statements for your own code.

Comment: This is tricky in practice, right? You put it before a `ns` form? Or after?

Comment: @DavidJames It unfortunately requires splitting `ns` form into real `ns` for external stuff followed by `set!` followed by a bunch of `require` and `use` calls for internal stuff.